# Weird issue using static map in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an issue that I don't understand why it happens. In a nutshell, I would like to create a singleton to read a configuration file where each property will be stored in a map.

I defined my configuration class (.h) as

```
class Configuration {
public:
    static Configuration* getInstance(std::string configFile);

private:
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> properties;
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static Configuration *instance;

    Configuration();
    Configuration(std::string configFile);
    ~Configuration();
};
```

On the implementation class I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Configuration.h"

std::map<std::string, std::string> Configuration::properties {};
bool Configuration::instanceFlag = false;
Configuration *Configuration::instance = NULL;
```

The issue is, my variable properties is the type of Configuration instead of a map. If a replace the key and value to be a int, the properties becomes a map. It seems weird.

I included string on my header file.

There is not exception or error. I mean, the compilation runs fine not error. However, my map is always empty. Debugging it on eclipse I noticed that the type of the variable properties is Configuration instead of map.

When I change the key and value type from string to int, the type of the object properties is map.

Have you seen it before? What am I missing here?

Thanks
Mauro

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you get any build errors or warnings? Can you please edit your question to include them (in full, complete, unmodified and copy-pasted as text)?

Comment: By the way, you *do* include `<string>` somewhere?

Comment: Not your question, but save yourself some grief and use a static local. And don't use pointers for things that can't be null, use pointers. And reconsider whether this should be a Singleton, or even a global.

Comment: @NirFriedman "Don't use pointers, use pointers"?

Comment: Clearly meant references, a strange brain fart I'm oddly prone too.

Comment: It sounds like you're misreading the debugger output , or perhaps the debugger is not displaying the map contents correctly

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Even my crystal ball doesn't want to take a stab at this without seeing the contents of `getInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a gdb bug, not the problem of your compiler or code.

On gdb, I could evaluate the following:

```
ptype Configuration::properties.instanceFlag
```

And it returns `type = bool`. gdb really interprets your `properties` to be of type `Configuration`.

But if change `private:` to `public:` and put the line `Configuration::properties.instanceFlag = true` on `main()`, g++ emits following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:26:28: error: ‘class std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘instanceFlag’
  Configuration::properties.instanceFlag = true;
```

Implies that your complier understands it fine. Tested with g++-5.4.0 and gdb-7.11.1 under ubuntu.

**EDIT** The self-contained example is:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Configuration {
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> properties;
    static bool instanceFlag;
};

std::map<std::string, std::string> Configuration::properties {};
bool Configuration::instanceFlag = false;

int main(void)
{
    Configuration::properties.instanceFlag = true;
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that the file name is mytest.cpp, if you compile it with `g++ mytest.cpp -std=c++11` it should emit the following error.

```
mytest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mytest.cpp:14:28: error: ‘class std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘instanceFlag’
  Configuration::properties.instanceFlag = true;
```

If you see the above error, that means you're fine. It is just bug of gdb, and your code will not have any problem using the static map.

If that compiies without error, THAT IS a problem.

Comment: My versions are: g++ 7.2.0 and gdb 8.0.1. Also using ubuntu

Comment: @MauroSilva Does not your g++ emit equivalent error message when you add `Configuration::properties.instanceFlag = true`?

Comment: If I set the value of Configuration::properties.instanceFlag to true, the object properties is not instantiate.

Comment: @MauroSilva On gdb or g++? See the edit of my answer.